# Pass the same value in two different arrays - VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

i m passing the same value to two different arrays using:

```
arrHo(0) = BoTeHa
arrAw(0) = BoTeHa
```

The above code works fine BUT i m wondering if there any other way to pass the value in both arrays in the same line like:

```
arrHo(0)  And arrAw(0) =BoTeHa
```

Comment: `arrHo(0) = BoTeHa : arrAw(0) = BoTeHa` ? but it would not be really 1 line, but 2 lines resumed in 1.

Comment: Just what I thought @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns :)

Comment: Why can't you just do: `arrHo(0) = arrAw(0) = BoTeHa`?